# Make code uncaseSensitive, Python, Discord Bot

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

How can i make this code icaseSensitive? I have tried `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=';', case_insensitive=True`
Is the code i have here on the rewrite branch? I know how on `async def on_message` but have heard it is not that smart to use `async def on_message`

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=';', case_insensitive=True)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("Admin")
async def info(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="{}'s info:".format(user.name), description="Here is his description. Bounty is around 1000 Dubloons", color=0x00ff00)
    embed.add_field(name="Navn", value=user.name, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="ID", value=user.id, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Status", value=user.status, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Høyeste rolle", value=user.top_role)
    embed.add_field(name="Ble med", value=user.joined_at)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
    await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

---

edit:

```
    from itertools import product

def aliases(info):
    return [''.join(item) for item in product(*((c.lower(), c.upper()) for c in info))]

@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=aliases('info'))
@commands.has_role("Admin")
async def info(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="{}'s info:".format(user.name), description="Here is his description. Bounty is around 1000 Dubloons", color=0x00ff00)
    embed.add_field(name="Navn", value=user.name, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="ID", value=user.id, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Status", value=user.status, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Høyeste rolle", value=user.top_role)
    embed.add_field(name="Ble med", value=user.joined_at)
    embed.set_footer(text="© Solmester123456 // Thomas")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
    await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `import discord; print(discord.__version__)`.  The rewrite branch is 1.0, the async branch is 0.16.  I suspect you're on the async branch.

A stopgap solution would be to register every mixed capitlization as an alias, something like

```
from itertools import product

def aliases(word):
    variations = (''.join(item) for item in product(*((c.lower(), c.upper()) for c in word)))
    return [item for item in variations if item != word]
    # registering the name of the coroutine as an alias causes it to fail

@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=aliases('info'))
@commands.has_role("Admin")
async def info(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    ...
```

Edit: This was previously not working because `product` returns tuples instead of strings, so we need to join them to make words.